# AngularJs Directive two way binding: How to preserve reference?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive

I have a directive which has a two way binding with an attribute. I want to re-assign the attribute in the link function. However, this breaks the reference.

What is the proper way of doing this?

```
<div ng-app="zippyModule">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl3">Title:
        <input ng-model="title">
        <div class="zippy" zippy-title="obj">{{obj.a}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function Ctrl3($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
        a: "a",
        b: "b"
    };
}

angular.module('zippyModule', [])
    .directive('zippy', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            title: '=zippyTitle'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            title = {
                a: "C",
                b: "D"
            };
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6HcGS/617/

Comment: `title` isn't within scope of directive for `ng-model` , not really sure what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Html**

```
<div ng-app="zippyModule">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl3">Title:
        <input ng-model="title.a">
        <div zippy="" zippy-title="title"></div>
            {{title.a}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
function Ctrl3($scope) {
    $scope.title = {
        a: "a",
        b: "b"
    };
}

angular.module('zippyModule', [])
    .directive('zippy', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            zippyTitle: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.zippyTitle.a = 'Test Title';
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6HcGS/619/

Comment: If the object is gigantic, and I don't want to assign the new value key by key. Is there a better way around?

Answer (score 0):

A few things are wrong here.

1) Close your input : `<input ng-model="title">`

2) Your module should have `restrict` just to be explicit, and typically you use template to get where your going. That said you've setup an isolated scope, with variable called `title`, then you call `obj` which doesn't exist in this scope.

```
angular.module('zippyModule', [])
.directive('zippy', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        title: '=zippyTitle'
    },
    template: 'TEMPLATE = {{title}}',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = {
            a: "C",
            b: "D"
        };
    }
  };
});
```

3) You call your directive wrong, it should be `<div zippy ....`  not a class.

Forked fiddle for fun. Note I left some stuff in just as examples.

http://jsfiddle.net/RomanKolo/j88CG/

EDIT:: You COULD use classes if you set `restrict: 'C'`

Answer (score -1):

You need:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = {
            a: "C",
            b: "D"
        };
    }
```

Notice the scope.title thingy, if you don't do that "title" is just a global object with no reference to you title object in the scope.